# (pagination,searching) showing many page when only 1 item is needed to show

Tags: php, mysqli

my problem is when i search a data using the search input box and the result is only 1 line of data the paging must only show (1) icon below, but the paging always show (1)(2)(3)(4) icons. any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated.

here the image when i search a data. it only show 1 line of data but the pagination number show 1,2,3,4. and the next pages is blank.

[image]

what i want to look like is this

[image]

here is the code

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    session_start();

?>

<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "srdatabase";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $results_per_page = 10;
    $select= "SELECT * FROM reservations";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
    $number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if(!isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }

    $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;

    $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);

?>

<div id="paging-div">

<?php
    if (!empty($_GET['valueToSearch'])) 
    {
        $valueToSearch = $_GET['valueToSearch'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE CONCAT(firstname, lastname, emailaddress, contactnumber, speaker, topic, location, audience, count, time, date, reservationdate, reservationstatus)LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%' LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;
        $search_result = filterTable($query);

    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM reservations LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;;
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }

    function filterTable($query)
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "srdatabase");
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        return $filter_Result;
    }
?>

<?php
    for($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++)
        {
            echo "<a id='pagingLink' href='adminControl.php?page=" . $page . "&valueToSearch=". urlencode($_GET['valueToSearch']) ."'>" . $page . "</a>";
        }   

?>
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin Control</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="speaker.php">Speakers</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="reservation.php">Reservation</a></li>
        <li><a href="signOut.php" id="signOut">Sign Out</a></li>
        <li><a href="myAccount.php" id="user" style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="signUp.php" id="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="signIn.php" id="signIn">Sign In</a></li>
        <li><a href="adminControl.php" id="adminControl" style="width:130px;">Admin control</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="pull">Speaker Reservation</a>
</nav>

<h4 style="padding-left:10px; text-align:center;">Reservation List</h4>
<hr>

<form action="adminControl.php" method="GET">
<input id="searchBox" type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="type information here">
<input id="searchButton" type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table class="reservations-table">
    <tr>
        <th class="thFirstName">First Name</th>
        <th class="thLastName">Last Name</th>
        <th class="thEmailAddress">Email Address</th>
        <th class="thContactNumber">Contact Number</th>
        <th class="thSpeaker">Speaker</th>
        <th class="thTopic">Topic</th>
        <th class="thLocation">Location</th>
        <th class="thAudience">Audience</th>
        <th class="thCount">Count</th>
        <th class="thTime">Time</th>
        <th class="thDate">Date</th>
        <th class="thAction">Reservation Date</th>
        <th class="thAction">Status</th>
        <th class="thAction">Action</th>
        <th class="thAction">Action</th>
    </tr>
     <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['firstname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['lastname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['emailaddress'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['contactnumber'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['speaker'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['topic'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['location'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['audience'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['count'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['time'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['reservationdate'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['reservationstatus'];?></td>
                    <td id="approve" align ='center'><a style="color:white;" href='adminControl.php?epr=approve&id=".$row['id']."'>APPROVE</a></td>
                    <td id="delete" align ='center'><a  style="color:white;" href='adminControl.php?epr=delete&id=".$row['id']."'>DELETE</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>

<?php

    $epr='';
    $msg='';
    if(isset($_GET['epr']))
    $epr=$_GET['epr'];

    if($epr=='delete')
    {
       $id=$_GET['id'];
       $delete=mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM reservations WHERE id=$id");
       if($delete)
         header('location:adminControl.php');
       else
         $msg='Error :'.mysqli_error(); 
    }
?>

<?php

    $epr='';
    $msg='';
    if(isset($_GET['epr']))
    $epr=$_GET['epr'];

    if($epr=='approve')
    {
       $id=$_GET['id'];
       $approve=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE reservations SET reservationstatus='approved' WHERE id=$id");
       header('location:adminControl.php');
    }
?>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

<script>
function ifAdmin() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("signIn").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signUp").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<script>
function ifNotAdmin() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("signIn").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signUp").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<script>
function ifNotLogin() 
{ 
   document.getElementById("user").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("signOut").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("adminControl").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['signedIn']) && $_SESSION['signedIn'] == true) 
        //if login
        {
            if($_SESSION['type'] == 1)
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifAdmin();</script>";  
            }
            elseif($_SESSION['type'] == 0)
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifNotAdmin();</script>";
            }
        }
        //if not login
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ifNotLogin();</script>";   
        }
?>

<div id="footer" class="push">Copyright 2017</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? Without it's hard to help you with your problem.

Comment: oh sorry i thought i already add it. thanks for asking.

Comment: If you echo out `$number_of_results` and `$number_of_pages` as soon as they're calculated, what do you get?

Comment: number of results = 31, number of pages = 4

Comment: So, the result isn't just one row as you say in your question, it's 31 rows.  The four page icons are appearing correctly.  I think your code is fine, but your search isn't returning what you think it should.

Comment: okay i will try if i can fix the search function tommorow cause its already 5am here thanks for your help.